# Downloading an arbitrary number of files from a URL with urllib2 in Python 2.7. Equivalent of "os.walk" for urllib2?

Tags: python, download, urllib2, os.walk

I'd like to download all of the files in a particular directory at a known URL. The names of the files won't necessarily be known, but their names will all contain a common keyword, and will have the same extension (.xml).

Is there an equivalent of "os.walk" for urllib2, such that I can simply walk through whatever files exist in the directory and open them for parsing?

The only examples of this I have seen online involve a a file of known name which contains a list of all the filenames in the directory. I do NOT want to do this...

Other possibly relevant info:
The files are on an apache server, and they are publicly accessible.

Comment: contact site owner and ask if theyd be willing to give data

Comment: it's actually my data. I just want to be able to pull it down with my script automatically without having to update a list of files in the directory every time it updates... maybe i'll have to do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible without knowing the filenames - you'd have to randomly try every possible name, because your only way of knowing if a file with this name exists is requesting the url and seeing if you get a response. But you could let the Apache webserver generate a directory index for you (with [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html)) and parse this to get the filenames.